# compare two different output of queries in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two table which connected with each other Primary key - Foreign Key.
I want to check their output are matching or not.

1. Query ::

`Select LINK_ID as A1, PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES as count1 from RDF_NAV_LINK where PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES is not null`

```
RecNo    | A1           | count1
-----------------------------------
1        |51364636      |2
2        |51366793      |1
3        |51366795      |1
4        |51366796      |4
```

1. Query ::

`Select LINK_ID as A2, count(*) as count2 from RDF_LANE Group by LINK_ID`

```
RecNo   |A2         |count2
----------------------------------
1       |51364636   |2
2       |51366793   |2
3       |53676455   |3
4       |53676460   |1
```

Now I want to check if **A1 = A2 then count1 have to equals count2** (if not is my output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both your selects on `A1 = A2 AND count1 <> count2`

```js
SELECT * FROM
(Select LINK_ID as A1, PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES as count1 from RDF_NAV_LINK where PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES is not null) X
INNER JOIN
(Select LINK_ID as A2, count(*) as count2 from RDF_LANE Group by LINK_ID) Y
ON A1 = A2 AND count1 <> count2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  (
   Select LINK_ID AS A1, PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES AS Count1 
   FROM RDF_NAV_LINK 
   WHERE PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES IS NOT NULL
  )S JOIN
  (
   Select LINK_ID AS A2, Count(*) As Count2 
   FROM RDF_LANE 
   GROUP BY LINK_ID
  )T ON T.A1 = S.A1 AND T.Count2 <> S.Count1
) Tmp
```